# Showing $r^{n/2} \in D_{2n}$ commutes with $f$ (where $n \equiv 0 \text { mod }2$)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, dihedral-groups

This is part of a bigger problem, but I just wanted to ensure the work I did in this portion is correct.

I'm using the generators $r$ and $f$, where $r^n=e$, $f^2=e$, and $rf=fr^{n-1}$.

Here's my proof:

> Consider the group $D_{2n}$ where $n \equiv 0 \text { mod }2$ and the element $r^{n/2}$. Then
>
> $r^{n/2}f=r^{n/2-1}(rf)=r^{n/2-1}fr^{n-1}=r^{n/2-2}(rf)r^{n-1}=r^{n/2-2}fr^{2(n-1)} = \dots = fr^{n/2(n-1)}=f\left(r^{n-1}\right)^{n/2}=f\left(r^{-1}\right)^{n/2}=f\left(r^{n/2}\right)^{-1}=fr^{n/2}.$ As needed.

Also, as a notational note, $D_{2n}$ is the dihedral group of order $2n$. (So $D_6$ is the dihedral group of a triangle).

Comment: You could save a few characters by writing $r^{n-1}$ as $r^{-1}$ throughout.

Comment: Will do :) I take it it looks good then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proofs seems fine. You can also note that, because $r^n= 1$ we have that $r^{n/2} = r^{-n/2}$ and since $rf = fr^{-1}$ we have that $r^{n/2}f = fr^{-n/2} = fr^{n/2}$.

Comment: That's so beautifully concise! Thank you for sharing this. :)